# execute class in its own thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an `InstanceFactory` class which creates instances of a certain class, let's call it `instance` class. These instances are created in a `main()` method. On this instance class I currently make calls like `instance.init()`, `instance.put()`, `instance.stop()`.

Since everything runs in a single thread, and I discovered some performance issues, I want try running instance in a separate thread.

Which changes do I have to make to the instance class in order to let it run in a separate threads? Will I still be able to make the same calls, e.g. `instance.init()`?

**Update (code added):**

```
InstanceFactory instanceFactory = new InstanceFactory();
try (Instance instance = instanceFactory.create()) {
    instance.init();
    instance.doStuff();
    while ((input = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        instance.put(input);
    }
}
```

instance should run in its own thread.

Comment: `instance.start()` should start a new thread given it `extends Thread` or `implements Runnable`.

Comment: @AniketThakur Runnable.run() does not start a new thread.

Comment: @AniketThakur You said "*instance.start() should start a new thread given it extends Thread or implements Runnable*". `Runnable` does not have a `start` method.

Comment: Please give us a bit of context. Is put() the method that takes a long time to complete?

Comment: what you mean? i already updated the question with code.

Comment: Yeah you will have to wrap it in Thread.

Comment: @JaagupKümmel: yes .put() takes a long time.

Comment: @JaagupKümmel no one said anything about calling run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

If `instance.put()` is thread-safe, you can replace `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();` with `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` for example.

```
InstanceFactory instanceFactory = new InstanceFactory();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
try (Instance instance = instanceFactory.create()) {
    instance.init();
    instance.doStuff();
    while ((input = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                instance.put(input);
            }
        });
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

Note: This is untested code.

Comment: is your answer still valid after this comment? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315314/execute-class-in-its-own-thread/31316001#comment50619459_31315314

Comment: what advantage do i get by replacing `newSingleThreadExecutor()` by `newCachedThreadPool()` ?

Comment: @beta `newSingleThreadExecutor` will only run one task at a time (useful, if multiple concurrent calls to `instance.put()` may cause errors).

Answer (score 2):

`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` creates only one *worker thread*, so you will have one *main thread +* one *worker thread* with a **FIFO queue** of `post()` tasks. If your `post()` method is **thread-safety** you should use `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` that creates so many threads as needed.

```
InstanceFactory instanceFactory = new InstanceFactory();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
try (Instance instance = instanceFactory.create()) {
    instance.init();
    instance.doStuff();
    while ((input = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                instance.put(input);
            }
        });
    }
} finally {
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

I advise you to read an [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) and some [guides](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html) about **ExecutorService**.

Comment: the other answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31316001/973158) says, that it is thread-safe if I use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` instead of `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`.

Comment: @beta, don't declare put() method as synchronized because only one thread will have permission to access it. You should declare as synchronized methods that are increasing array size for example.